# Angular 6 append svg onclick event

Tags: svg, angular6

I am trying to load a svg object inside my Angular app in noraml html I am using this code:

```
 <object data="assets/img/bihar.svg" id="biharsvg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

And it is loading fine but I want to load this object using a click event for that I have seen innerHTML but that is not working what would be the best way to appned this inside any div.

I am using this code:

```
 <div [innerHTML]="htmlContent"></div>
```

Inside my html and inside my component.ts I am using this code:

```
 this.htmlContent = `<h2>Hello</h2>`
```

And this work fine  when I am doing this:

```
   this.htmlContent = `<object data="assets/img/bihar.svg" id="biharsvg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>`
```

I am getting warning message :

```
WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content
```

And my svg object is not loading what would be the best way to append my object inside html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="loadsvg">
     <object data="assets/img/bihar.svg" id="biharsvg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

In the .ts file

```
public loadsvg = false;

onlcikLoadSvg(){
this.loadsvg =true;
}
```